# how to load and apply json vizmap (exported from Cy3) to cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

For loading the Cy3-exported network, this works great:

```
 cy.add(network.elements);  // where 'network' is the json object exported by Cy3
```

What command loads and applies the exported vizmap?  This command ran to completion, but the visual style of the network bears no resemblance to what we see in Cy3.

```
 cy.style().fromJson(vizmap).update()  // where 'vizmap' is the json vizmap object from Cy3
```

Advice, anyone?  Perhaps even a small example?

Thanks!

- Paul

Answer (score 0):

Rather than loading this data after init, have you tried using the init options instead.  That's where style is specified.

```
cytoscape({
  style: networkJson.path.to.style,
  elements: networkJson.path.to.elements
  // ...
});
```

Edit: It looks like Cytoscape-desktop generates JSON like this

```
[ {
  "title" : "hallmarksOfCancer",
  "style" : [ {
    "selector" : "node",
    "css" : {
      "text-opacity" : 1.0,
      "width" : 70.0,
      "border-opacity" : 1.0,
      "background-color" : "rgb(255,255,255)",
      "background-opacity" : 1.0,
      "font-size" : 20,
      "shape" : "ellipse",
      "border-width" : 1.0,
      "border-color" : "rgb(0,0,0)",
      "color" : "rgb(0,0,0)",
      "height" : 30.0,
      "text-valign" : "center",
      "text-halign" : "center",
      "font-family" : "SansSerif",
      "font-weight" : "bold",
      "content" : "data(label)"
    }
  }, {
    "selector" : "node[score > 4.6]",
    "css" : {
      "width" : 140.0
    }
  }, {
    "selector" : "node[score = 4.6]",
    "css" : {
      "width" : 140.0
    }
  }, {
    "selector" : "node[score > 0.0][score < 4.6]",
    "css" : {
      "width" : "mapData(score,0.0,4.6,70.0,140.0)"
    }
  }, {
```

In that case, you can use something like `style: visjson[i].style` in your init options, where `i` ranges on `0 <= i <= visjson.length`.  Cytoscape desktop exports several stylesheets at once, so you 'll need to specify which one (i.e. `i`) you want to use.

Comment: Hi Max,  Thanks for that suggestion.  I moved both the style and elements data to the initialization code.   The elements(the network) comes out fine, leading me to believe my technique is basically sound.  But the json for style has no effect.  I know I sound like a broken record on this :{ but is there a live example I can study to see what I am doing wrong?    Thanks - Paul

Comment: Could you post your json?

Comment: I cannot figure out how to post 2374 (!) lines of json here, so as a temporary expedient, I am emailing the file "vizmap.json" to Max directly.   This file works great with Kei's drag-and-drop app of last week.  I will attach the network.json file too, just in case.  - Paul